# Trying to run LDAP query from Linux command line

Tags: linux, ldap, ldap-query

I want to run an LDAP query from a command line on a linux system. (CentOS 5.8)
 i.e., I want to run the following query to look up a user's DN:

`(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=username))`

How can I run this LDAP query from a linux command line and have it return query results for the provided username? I have red up on using LDAPSEARCH but cannot locate it on my CentOS 5.8 distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't find *ldapsearch* then install it (should be within package *openldap-clients*)